# how to make date only show weekends (saturday and sunday) for a month?

Tags: python, date, flask, web-applications, visual-studio-2019

i want to make ticketing form using flask in visual studion 2019. user must input some information like amount of person (max 4), names (depend on how max person input), and date.

i want to make this date only show weekends (saturday and sunday) for this month. for example : if user pick date today (31 July), the date will show only weekends for the next 31 days. any help? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what date type you are using but numpy has some nice business day functionality;

```
import numpy as np

date = np.datetime64("today")
dates = np.arange(date, date + 31)
mask = ~np.is_busday(dates)

print(dates[mask])
```